Cannot call get properties from typescript class
export class MyModel {
trnMinDate: string | null = null;
trnMaxDate: string | null = null;

get trnMinimumDate(): Date | null{
  if (!this.trnMinDate) return null
    return new Date(this.trnMinDate);
  
}

get trnMaximumDate(): Date | null {
  if (!this.trnMaxDate) return null
  return new Date(this.trnMaxDate);
}
}

This is my modal class for the angular project. I am fetching data from an API and assigning the values for trnMinDate and trnMaxDate. my app.component.ts file is in the following content.
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;       
  ngOnInit() 
   {
           const fetchDataFromApi$ = this._myService.getData();
           fetchDataFromApi$.subscribe({
                next: (data: MyModel ) => {
                     console.log('min-trn-date',data.trnMinDate)//value is logging
                     console.log('max-trn-date',data.trnMaxDate)//value is logging

                     this.minDate=data.trnMinimumDate;
                     this.maxDate=data.trnMaximumDate;

                     console.log('min-date-value',this.minDate)//value is logging as undefined
                     console.log('max-date-value',this.maxDate)//value is logging as undefined
                },
                error: (error) => {

                }
           })
   }
}

When I log it(min-date-value & max-date-value) like this, both values are logged as undefined. but trnMinDate and trnMaxDate have string values.  I cannot find the issue. Can anyone help me sort it out?

Have you tried printing both data.trnMinimumDate and data.trnMaximumDate and see is there any value?

Do you actually instantiate the class anywhere? Or do you just have a vanilla object?

Set a breakpoint inside the function right before you log the values. What does data look like? Also look at the response of the API call in the Network tab of Developer tools. Does it have the structure you expected? The key here is learning the debugger in your browser.

 fetchDataFromApi$.subscribe({
                next: (data: MyModel ) => {
                     console.log('min-trn-date',data.trnMinDate)//value is logging
                     console.log('max-trn-date',data.trnMaxDate)//value is logging

                     // HERE you set trnMinimumDate - but before you log trnMinDate
                     this.minDate=data.trnMinimumDate;
                     this.maxDate=data.trnMaximumDate;

                     console.log('min-date-value',this.minDate)//value is logging as undefined
                     console.log('max-date-value',this.maxDate)//value is logging as undefined
                },
                error: (error) => {

                }
           })

What I see is you log the data.trnMinDate. But you set the data.trnMinimumDate. Please log the current value and have a look to its content.

This is a situation where your browser’s debug tools are your friend. Open developer tools (if unsure how, Google how to open developer tools for your specific browser). Find the tab that lets you see your code. Find your file and set a breakpoint inside the function right before you log the values. Do whatever is needed in your application to make the line you set a breakpoint on run. What does data look like? Does it have the properties you expect with the spelling and case you expect? Now find the Network tab and look at the response of the API call. Does it have the structure you expected (depending on your browser you may need to open the Network tab once before running the app to let it know to record API calls)?
Getting undefined when accessing an object property in JavaScript/TypeScript means the property doesn’t exist on the object (unless it was explicitly set to undefined but that’s less common and not relevant here). You’re likely making a wrong assumption about the structure of the API call response, and the first step is to see what you’re actually getting. You can do that with console.log, but the debug tools in your browser make this much easier without having to clutter your code with console.log statements.

I believe that if you try to check and print the data instance type with data instanceof MyModel, it results in false.
You need additional steps to make the data from the Observable as a MyModel instance.

A constructor to extract passed data and create a MyModel instance.

export class MyModel {
  public trnMinDate: string | null = null;
  public trnMaxDate: string | null = null;
  [key: string]: any;

  constructor(instance: MyModel) {
    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(this);

    for (let key of keys) {
      if (instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) this[key] = instance[key];
    }
  }

  get trnMinimumDate(): Date | null {
    if (!this.trnMinDate) return null;
    return new Date(this.trnMinDate);
  }

  get trnMaximumDate(): Date | null {
    if (!this.trnMaxDate) return null;
    return new Date(this.trnMaxDate);
  }
}


Work with map RxJS operator to convert the data as a MyModel instance.

import { map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class MyService {
  getData(): Observable<MyModel> {
    return <Your Original observable instance>
      .pipe(map((data: any) => new MyModel(data)));
  }
}

Demo @ StackBlitz
